# ¿Como puedo guardar la hora en mi BD?

Tags: php, mysql

Este es mi formulario el cual tengo una variable hora que esta sincronizado con la hora del pc lo que busco poder registrar la hora en mi BD el problema es que no esta guardando.

**formato.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <title>Formato De Servicio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Regulacion</h1>
    <form  action="guardarFormato.php" method="post">

        <?php
        date_default_timezone_set("America/BOGOTA" ) ;
        $hora = date('h:i a',time() - 3600*date('I'));
        ?>

    <label>Hora:<input type=text name="hora" <?php echo "value='$hora'";?> disabled></label>
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

**guardarFormato.php**

```
<?php
    // Abrimos la conexion a la base de datos   
    $conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin123","database");

    // Recibimos por POST los datos procedentes del formulario   
    $hora = $_POST["hora"];

    $guardar = "INSERT INTO servicio (hora) VALUES ('".$hora."') ";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$guardar);
    if (!$resultado) {
        echo '<script>
                alert("la hora fue registrada");
             </script>';

    }else{
            header("location:mostrarServicios.php");
          } 
   ?>
```

Comment: Primero que nada no entiendo porque cuando $resultado es falso dices que el servicio fue registrado, te recomiendo que leas la documentación de php http:/php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php, si es falso es que dio un error. Y otra detalle, has revisado tu base de datos, tu tabla se llama servicio, se llena cuando mandas tu formulario, da algún error????

Comment: no da niingun error eso no significa que sea falso,

Comment: si resultado es falso o null pasara tu primer if algo ke no tiene logica viendo lo que muestras a continuación

Comment: Veo que tu input donde guardas la hora esta disabled, me hace pensar que no deberias enviar la hora. En su lugar, cuando se envia tu formulario, pon directamente la hora que coja el sistema (la misma que tenga el servidor) y te quitas ese problema.

Comment: me puedes mostrar como?

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris, lo puedes hacer de esta forma: `$guardar = "INSERT INTO servicio (hora) VALUES ('".date('h:i')."') ";`